# Fail CI pipeline if Release fails

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to setup a branch policy where the build validation before completing the pull request must ensure that build and release pipelines are successful. I can fail the CI pipeline but I want to fail the CI pipeline if the deployment fails. How do I do this?

I am having a separate Release pipeline outside of the CI pipelines .yaml.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can set build validation for target branch. It will force your chosen build pipeline to run with files provided by pull request.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops

For release pipeline, add Pull Request trigger and set target branch. It will use artifacts from your build pipeline.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deploy-pull-request-builds?view=azure-devops

If anything fails pull request will be stopped.

Additional note(not fully connected with your question).
In Azure DevOps REST API there is endpoint that allow you to change pull request status for example to status "Abandoned" in special situations when you do not want to fail pipeline but want to stop pull request.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20requests/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1

Comment: Will this work if the deployment stage starts but actually deployment fails say e.g. IIS website could not be deleted?

Comment: When deployment by IIS fails and then this stage fail and then whole Pull Request should. Maybe the only exceptions would be if you set in task "Advanced" -> "Continue on error". But it is not by default.

Answer (score 0):

> I can fail the CI pipeline but I want to fail the CI pipeline if the
>   deployment fails.

Not sure how you used to fail the CI, but I have a method that could help you achieve do that once the deployment fail.

I wrote a simple extension, which it will add a post job into release pipeline. See my github repos [merlinLia/PostJob-extension](https://github.com/merlinLia/PostJob-extension).

```
  {
  "id": "release-octane-pipeline-end-decorator",
  "type": "ms.azure-pipelines.pipeline-decorator",
  "targets": [
    "ms.azure-release-pipelines-agent-job.post-job-tasks"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "template": "release-decorator.yml"
  }
}
```

This will add additional customized post job `release-decorator.yml` in release pipeline, and it can only be ran after all of your defined tasks finished.

[image]

In your scenario, you can apply with this pipeline decorator. And add the [condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/add-pipeline-decorator?view=azure-devops#conditional-injection) into [release-decorator.yml](https://github.com/merlinLia/PostJob-extension/blob/master/release-decorator.yml), for example, this customized post job can only be ran after your previous task failed.

And, in this customized post job definition, you could apply with your idea that make CI failed, including powershell script.

---

*My extension just used for myself, so I did not public it in marketplace. You can refer to my code and create yourself one.*

---

**Update** for the summary of my idea.

Since you just want a strict pull request policy that if the deployment failed, the pull request should not be allowed to completed.

Based on my suggestion, you can run one task after all deploy tasks finished. And in this task, it get the previous deploy tasks status firstly. When it get the order that previous task is failed, it will run one scripts to change the pull request status, like `Abandoned`.

Combine with my original idea, you could create a extension that it will inject one post-job into pipeline automatically. This job will do the work (modify pull request) automatically by setting **condition** into script, and this condition can be customized by yourself, including only some of projects can apply this post-job into pipeline.

The [api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20requests/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) of modify the PR is(it can be applied in pipeline of all projects since I get the parameters by using pre-defined variables):

```
PATCH 

$($env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONCOLLECTIONURI)$env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECTID/_apis/git/repositories/$($env:BUILD_REPOSITORY_ID)/pullrequests/$($env:BUILD_PULLREQUEST_ID)?api-version=5.1
```

**Request body(`Abandon`):**

```
{"status":2}
```

Comment: I meant `continueOnError: false` so that the CI pipeline will fail in case say unit test stage fails.

Comment: Is there a documentation reference that you can provide so that I can have the basic minimum knowledge to understand your approach?

Comment: @Chubsdad, yes, sure. Please see this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/add-pipeline-decorator?view=azure-devops. This is the new feature we provided last month. You can have a look.

Comment: @Chubsdad. (Here is response for you first comment). If so, can I consider you want to modify the original build result after the deploy finished? If so, I'm afraid you can not do. The **result** filed is hard code by our system, and there's no way to modify the **result** filed directly, including API. The work around you can considered is **status** field, this is one that we can modify it by [api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/update%20build?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#buildstatus).

Comment: All I want to know is if the deployment through the Release pipeline succeeded or not after the CI build succeeds. If deployment fails, fail the pull request.

Comment: Your approach on the first pass looks promising, except that it affect the whole org. Some projects in our org may not have such stringent requirements. Is it possible to do it per project/pipeline?

Comment: @Chubsdad, If this, we don't need consider how to modify one succeed pipeline failed manually(hardly to achieve). Just consider on how to make the deployment result has relationship on the PR. 2) Of course yes, you can restrict that extension to let it only make affect on some of projects. For example, you can filter the project by setting condition in that extension script. I will update more for how to make it have affect on PR failed after looking for some docs to you.

Comment: @Chubsdad, I updated more details of my idea. You can have a check.